# How can I prevent multiple injection/execution of content script(s) in response to a single event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension that responds to click events on a context menu.

My background script creates the context menu using the `chrome.contextMenus.create` api method call and sets a click handler as shown in the code below:

```
//event.js
function onItemClick(info, tab){
    // Inject the content script into the current page
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'content.js' });

    // Perform the callback when a message is received from the content script
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message){
        var url = "data:text/html;charset=utf8,";

        function append(key, value){
            var input = document.createElement('textarea');
            input.setAttribute('name', key);
            input.textContent = value;
            form.appendChild(input);
        }

        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.method = 'POST';
        form.action = 'http://localhost/myapp/myapp.php';
        form.style.visibility = "hidden";
        append('url', message.url);
        append('text', message.selectedText);
        url = url + encodeURIComponent(form.outerHTML);
        url = url + encodeURIComponent('<script>document.forms[0].submit();</script>');
        chrome.tabs.create({url: url, active: true});
    });
}

var context = "selection";
var title = "Share in new tab";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts": [context], "onclick": onItemClick});
```

The background script above programmatically creates a form that automatically gets submitted in a new tab. In doing so, it calls a "content script" below to get some information from the current page/tab.

```
//content.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    'url': window.location.href,
    'selectedText': window.getSelection().toString()
});
```

The problem is this. The click handler in the background script injects the "content script" into the current page multiple times (that is, every time the click handler is called). As a result of this multiple injection, each injected instance of the "content script" is executed resulting in multiple new tabs/pages being opened. The number of new tabs opened increases by one each time the context menu item is clicked suggesting the problem is indeed multiple injection and execution of the content script. How can I inject the content script only once, or at least ensure that only one "instance" of the injected scripts sends a message back to my background script?

I have tried to automatically inject the script in the manifest, but calling `chrome.tabs.executeScript` thereafter results in an endless creation of tabs. So, I really need to be able to inject the script on demand, but find a way to either prevent multiple injections or at least ensure only one "injection" sends a message back. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can be achieved easily: you can create a global control variable in the content script. Check for it at the beginning, and if it is not `true` then set it to `true` and proceed. The first content script that gets executed will set the variable and prevent others from doing anything.

By the way, I see you're adding a listener to `chrome.runtime.onMessage` inside another listener: that is not good practice, because it will add multiple listeners for the same event and result in executing them multiple times. You should instead declare the listener outside, sending a different message saying "do something" or "do something else".

In the content script:

```
// Warning! Comparing to a literal to ignore a DOM element with id=messageSent
// which automatically creates an implicit global on `window`
if (window.messageSent !== true) {
    window.messageSent = true;

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        action: "submit the form",
        url: window.location.href,
        selectedText: window.getSelection().toString()
    });
}
```

In the `background.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message){
    if (message.action == "submit the form") {
        // do what you need to submit the form
        var url = "data:text/html;charset=utf8,";
        function append(key, value){
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks Marco. It turns out the multiple tabs were created because I added the "onMessage" listener inside the "onClick" listener. Thanks for pointing this out. It makes perfect sense that multiple listeners were being created leading to multiple executions...

Comment: Doesn't `itemClicked` in this code snippet get set in the context of the extension's background script, thus it will be set until you restart the browser?  This means you can only ever inject into one page _ever_ for the life of your browser session.  It seems you would want the flag associated with an individual page, not with the plugin's background script.

Comment: @MicahZoltu you're right. I'll edit my answer to fix it.