# reloading chrome extension fails because symbols already defined. How to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have [written a Chrome extension](https://github.com/metaperl/baduk-flash/blob/main/README.md#how-to-use) that takes a screenshot of a Go (a board game) board and then downloads the screenshot to the local system.

Although the extension works, I cannot invoke the extension twice in a row without reloading the page because if I attempt to do so, I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'BadukFlash' has already been declared (at baduk_flash.js:1:1)
```

Comment: I have no clairvoyant powers, but I want to gamble by claiming that "BadukFlash" was declared with the **const** keyword. Did I get it?

Comment: Why use clairvoyant powers when you can look at the code - https://github.com/metaperl/baduk-flash/blob/main/baduk_flash.js#L20  ... no, there is not a const keyword.

Comment: I thought it was a link to the CWS and I didn't click on it. My bad, sorry

Comment: All relevant code must be inside the question, see [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user clicks on the action, the extension injects `html2canvas.js` and `baduk_flash.js` into the active tab.

`baduk_flash.js` declares the class BadukFlash.

When the user clicks the action again, all of this happens again.
I.e. the class BadukFlash is re-declared.

At this point, `baduk_flash.js` stops executing, because of this uncaught syntax error.
If `baduk_flash.js` were to continue running, then the variable `bf` would also be re-declared.

Possible ways to fix this:

The cleanest way would be to inject the content script with static declarations, by using the field "content_scripts" in manifest.json:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#static-declarative

When the user clicks the action, the service worker should send a message to the content script in the active tab.

But then you have to know in advance what pages you want to inject the content script into. If you don't know that, you must inject it programmatically, and check if it's already been injected:

[How can I prevent multiple injection/execution of content script(s) in response to a single event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907941/how-can-i-prevent-multiple-injection-execution-of-content-scripts-in-response)

Comment: I follow your logic. So how should this extension be re-architected so that the injection only occurs on the first click of the extension button and so that the intended series of actions still runs? Intended series of actions is `bf.fetch_url(); bf.bf.toggleAI(); bf.snapScreenshot()`

Comment: Wrap everything in an IIFE?