# Load content script into all tabs, but only if the content script is not already loaded

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

**Problem**

My chrome extension needs to inject the content script into all tabs when switched on and then when any new tabs are loaded etc.

By adding the content script to the manifest file I can satisfy the second requirement of having it loaded in newly loaded tabs.

To make it also inject the content script into tabs as soon as the extension is loaded or refreshed (there is no popup), I am using `chrome.scripting.executeScript`.

Problem is each time the extension is turned off/on or refreshed, the content script is loaded in again and any DOM manipulation from content script occurs multiple times.

So from reading another post, I liked the idea of sending a message to the content script, if I don't get a response (`undefined`) then I inject the script into this tab, if I do get a response then do nothing.

In my background logs I get this error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.` which is what I would expect if the content script did not exist, but even when the content script is clearly being loaded, I still get the same error.

Any help greatly appreciated. And maybe this is not even the best approach for this, I am not sure.  Ideally I would also want the extension to immediately stop working when it's turned off, but I haven't got around to this problem yet.

**Manifest**

```
{
    "name": "Text highlighter",
    "description": "Text highlighter",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "options_ui": {
      "page": "options.html",
      "open_in_tab": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "css": [ "styles.css" ]
      }
    ],
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs"],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

```
self.oninstall = () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
        tabs.forEach((tab) => {         
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, true, (response) => {
                console.log('response', response);
                if(!response) {
                    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                        target: {tabId: tab.id},
                        files: ['content.js']
                    });
        
                    chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
                        target: { tabId: tab.id },
                        files: ['styles.css']
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log('request', request);
    sendResponse(true);

    return true;
});
```

Comment: [How can I prevent multiple injection/execution of content script(s) in response to a single event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27908068/19840875)

Comment: And then there's `chrome.scripting`, with `getRegisteredContentScripts`, `registerContentScripts` and `unregisterContentScripts`. I've never used them, though.

Comment: Replace `if(!response)` with `if(chrome.runtime.lastError)`

Comment: The registered content scrips thing is interesting, but while I was playing with it it seemed it does not inject immediately so requires a page refresh.

Comment: Tried using if(chrome.runtime.lastError) but still get undefined

Comment: The global variable is interesting.  I will have a go and see if I can get this to work for me.

Comment: Yeah so I tried with this Global variable but it doesn't seem to work for me.  Each time the extension is turned off and then back on, the window property I am setting is going back to being undefined, that I can see from the logs